# How can I aggregate multiple columns in a data.frame with a custom function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I've got a data.frame `dt` with some duplicate keys and missing data, i.e.

```
Name     Height     Weight   Age
Alice    180        NA       35
Bob      NA         80       27
Alice    NA         70       NA
Charles  170        75       NA
```

In this case the key is the name, and I would like to apply to each column a function like

```
f <- function(x){
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  x <- x[1]
  return(x)
  }
```

while aggregating by the key (i.e., the "Name" column), so as to obtain as a result

```
Name     Height     Weight   Age
Alice    180        70       35
Bob      NA         80       27
Charles  170        75       NA
```

I tried

```
dt_agg <- aggregate(. ~ Name,
                    data = dt,
                    FUN = f)
```

and I got some errors, then I tried the following

```
dt_agg_1 <- aggregate(Height ~ Name,
                      data = dt,
                      FUN = f)

dt_agg_2 <- aggregate(Weight ~ Name,
                      data = dt,
                      FUN = f)
```

and this time it worked.

Since I have 50 columns, this second approach is quite cumbersome for me. Is there a way to fix the first approach?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarize_all(funs(sort(.)[1]))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     Name Height Weight   Age
   <fctr>  <int>  <int> <int>
1   Alice    180     70    35
2     Bob     NA     80    27
3 Charles    170     75    NA
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "Name     Height     Weight   Age
Alice    180        NA       35
Bob      NA         80       27
Alice    NA         70       NA
Charles  170        75       NA", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You were very close with the `aggregate` function, you needed to adjust how aggregate handles `NA` (from `na.omit` to `na.pass`). My guess is that aggregate removes all rows with NA first and then does its aggregating, instead of removing NAs as aggregate iterates over the columns to be aggregated. Since your example dataframe you have an `NA` in each row you end up with a 0-row dataframe (which is the error I was getting when running your code). I tested this by removing all but one NA and your code works as-is. So we set `na.action = na.pass` to pass the NA's through.

```
dt_agg <- aggregate(. ~ Name,
                    data = dt,
                    FUN = f, na.action = "na.pass")
```

### original answer

```
dt_agg <- aggregate(dt[, -1], 
                    by = list(dt$Name),
                    FUN = f)
dt_agg
# Group.1 Height Weight Age
# 1   Alice    180     70  35
# 2     Bob     NA     80  27
# 3 Charles    170     75  NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) head(sort(x), 1)), Name]
#      Name Height Weight Age
#1:   Alice    180     70  35
#2:     Bob     NA     80  27
#3: Charles    170     75  NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, add `na.action=na.pass` in `aggregate()` call:

```
aggdf <- aggregate(.~Name, data=df, FUN=f, na.action=na.pass)
#      Name Height Weight Age
# 1   Alice    180     70  35
# 2     Bob     NA     80  27
# 3 Charles    170     75  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add an `ifelse()` to your function to make sure the function returns a value if all values are `NA`:

```
f <- function(x) {
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  ifelse(length(x) == 0, NA, x)
}
```

You can use `dplyr` to aggregate:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise_all(funs(f))
```

This returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     Name Height Weight   Age
   <fctr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1   Alice    180     70    35
2     Bob     NA     80    27
3 Charles    170     75    NA
```